# Why only run 32-bit VMs inside another VM

Tags: nested, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Can someone explain in technical terms why it is pt. not possible to have 64-bit VMs inside another VM?

fx. running a VirtualBox within a VirtualBox -- on a strong and fast windows server 64bit

Comment: Honestly I don't know why technically it is not possible, but logically it is not advised because it will not be effective in term of resources consumption and drastically decrease the performance.

Comment: well there could be issues with applications expecting the 64bit architecture, so for these types of applications it is vital that the VM is running in that scope